# use checkedlistbox and get this result "system.data.datarowview"

Tags: vb.net, checkboxlist

When I use this simple code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
   
    Dim cheq As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        cheq.Append(item)
        cheq.Append(" ")

    Next
    MessageBox.Show(" Your Checked Items are : " & cheq.ToString())
End Sub
```

and wait for the message I find this result

```
Your Checked Items are : system.data.datarowview
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code, only a mismatch of your expectations. This CheckedListBox is bound to a datatable. When a control binds to a datatable, it actually attaches to the DataView exposed by the DefaultView property, and a DataView is a colelction of DataRowView

Presumably you want to get access to the underlying DataRow, available via the Row property of the DataRowView. It might be mostly unnecessary; you can get values out of a DataRowView in the same way as you would a DataRow; if your DataRow represents a person with a Name column then either of these will give you the name:

```
DirectCast(DirectCast(item, DataRowView)("Name"), String)
DirectCast(DirectCast(item, DataRowView).Row("Name"), String)
```

Or to tidy it a little:

```
For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of DataRowView)
    cheq.Append(item("SOME_COLUMN_NAME_HERE"))
    cheq.Append(" ")

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a `DataTable`, the data comes from its `DefaultView`, which is a `DataView`. Each item in a `DataView` is a `DataRowView` and, like most types, calling `ToString` on one will simply return the type name.

You are presumably setting the `DisplayMember` of your `CheckedListBox` in order to specify which column of your `DataTable` the values should be drawn from to be displayed in the control. If what you actually want is the text that is displayed for the item then you should be calling the `GetItemText` method:

```vb
Dim itemText = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.
                               Cast(Of Object).
                               Select(Function(o) CheckedListBox1.GetItemText(o))

MessageBox.Show("Checked Items: " & String.Join(", ", itemText))
```

Comment: Cast(Of DataRowView) ?

Comment: @CaiusJard, `GetItemText` takes an `Object` reference as an argument so there's no need to cast as type `DataRowView`, although it won't hurt.